# Change clock to 24-hours mode on radio in Honda Element

Tags: honda, audio, element

Is there a way to change the settings on a factory-installed CD-radio unit that came with my 2004 *Honda Element* to display the clock in 24-hour mode?

Looked in the owners manual, but no mention there.

Comment: What year is your Element? Which radio came with it?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Mine is year 2004, but it would be nice if an Answer could list the various methods for all units. Hopefully there is only one or a very few ways to set such a preference assuming Honda sources their radios from a single supplier.

Comment: I don't beleive this is possible for US LX, Canadian DX, and all EX models.  The clock isn't *smart* enough, it's not just a preference to display that way.  I can't speak for vehicles outside of North America.

Comment: Really this question is too broad to answer, unless the answer is you cannot do it. I agree with @SteveRacer as well, I don't think the clock is smart enough to do this as you are suggesting.

Comment: I checked a few variations 2004 Owner's Manuals as did the OP, and I suspect the reason there's no mention of it is simply that the feature doesn't exist.

Comment: I take it "Use the car before one o'clock in the afternoon only" isn't the answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://honda-tech.com/forums/honda-fit-73/24-hour-clock-how-1614086/) seems to suggest that no Honda supports this function and that their inbuilt clocks only provide AM/PM display.